# Update Query Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, netbeans

i have this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE fID = ''2'' at line 1"

Code:

```
String query = "UPDATE fooditem SET fName = '"
               +fi.getFName()+"', fDesc = '"
               +fi.getFDesc()+"', fImgDir = '"
               +fi.getFImgDir()+"', fPrice = '"
               +fi.getFPrice()+"', WHERE fID = ''"+fi.getFItemID()+"'";

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
```

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: remove the comma before the `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

```
String query = "UPDATE fooditem SET fName = '"
               +fi.getFName()+"', fDesc = '"
               +fi.getFDesc()+"', fImgDir = '"
               +fi.getFImgDir()+"', fPrice = '"
               +fi.getFPrice()+"' WHERE fID = ''"+fi.getFItemID()+"'";

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
```

Remove the comma before `WHERE`